# download audio on onclick of button using audio.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I want download currently playing audio.. I used http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html..

```
function download() {
            $.ajax(
                     {
                         url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
                         success: function () {
                             alert("success");
                             var oAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
                             var url = oAudio.getAttribute('src');
                             var newurl = "http://192.168.0.13:80/" + url;
                             alert(newurl);
                             window.open(newurl);
                         },
                         error: function () {
                             alert("err");
                             var oAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
                             var url = oAudio.getAttribute('src');
                             alert(url);
                             window.open(url);
                         }

                     });
        }
```

It doesnot download audio..any solution plz

Comment: Why `var newurl = "http://localhost:56596/" + url;`?

Comment: I am just trying my own way ut it always goes in error part but doesnot download :( plz help @SonuJoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7o3qg3v2/2/)

Remove `var newurl = "http://localhost:56596/" + url;`

Append file url on download link on list item click event

```
$('ol li').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
          audio.load($('a', this).attr('data-src'));
          $('#download').attr('href', $('a', this).attr('data-src'));
          audio.play();
        });
```

Use HTML5 download attribute for that:

```
    $('#download').attr({'href' : $('a', this).attr('data-src'), 'download' : $('a', this).attr('data-src')});
```

Comment: not able to download file..its fetch only name of playing audio on onclick of download and start playing audio on new tab @SonuJoshi

Comment: it doesnot download song.. It download some other page

Comment: download attribute is working only in FF and chrome not in safari and IE :(

Comment: can window.open() helps to download audios?? I tried it but failed

Comment: It failed because modern browsers can play mp3s that is why download attribute is used to trigger forced downloads. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: is there any other way to do that bcz download functionality must be support in every browser (in my application)